# Fetch JWT token automatically when user calls rest api directly from browser and give access to api if fetched token is valid

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-ad-msal, flask-restful

I have a rest API written using Python Flask. I used the Azure MSAL library to validate the JWT tokens. When a user directly calls the rest API without any JWT token, I want to redirect the user to the Microsoft login, and once the user is authenticated, get that token, validate the token, and finally send the api response.All this has to be done at the server side. Is it possible to acheive this or Is there a better way to do this?

I managed to get the token using msal ConfidentialClientApplication.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(), it has some issues with the redirect uri's and I want to know if there is any better way to do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.